# What is in a library - interface backend (java) /frontend (js knockout)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, knockout.js, interface, namespaces

I am creating a web-application. Shortly to the app: Restful, the backend is written in Java, I use Wink. As for the frontend I want to use knockout.js, I already did some of the online tutorials to get used to the framework a bit.

I already was playing a bit and created ajax-calls for the add-delete-search functionalities and displayed the retrieved records on a simple html-page via knockout.js.
I got the proposal to create a library/namespace first, before starting on anything else of the frontend. So I decided to step back and try to create such lib.

Yes, I read tons of documentation in the internet (closure, namespace, javascript, libs in general, ...), but somehow I still get not further with the lib.

*Questions:*

- Main question is: What should be in that lib, if it is the interface backend/frontend?
- I was planning to create a closure (for private members). Will that closure be the namespace (am little scrued with the "namespace"-topic)?
- What actually should be in such library?

  - ajax-calls
  - all the ajax-Calls and all helper methods
  - view-model of knockout-js
  - template for displaying the dictionary? (Or is this another file..)

*My understanding of Library:*
A Lib is just a js-file, which includes variables and functions, that belong together (encapsulation). A lib makes a code reuseable.
Using a namespace in a library is good, to avoid collisions with other libs and using closures is good, to be able to "create" private and public variables and functions.
Am I wrong in any assumption from up there?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/), it's a spec for publishing WSDL-like metadata for RESTful resources. You could use something like [amdatu](http://www.amdatu.org/components/web.html) for the server-side part; it includes Wink and will generate Swagger metadata. You should be able to use that metadata to generate stubs for your Knockout viewmodels if you want. Then you can take the JavaScript Swagger UI, point it at the metadata, and it will generate functions for all ajax calls (so you won't need these in your library).

Comment: If you go that route, there won't be a whole lot left to put in the library; you'll mostly have UI-specific stuff that isn't easily reusable left to write, so there wouldn't be much point in trying to abstract it out into a library.

Comment: For now (this project) I rather wanted to learn how to do it in javascript. So the actual task of that project is learning: 'Getting a library written in js/knockout done'. Of course I also want to get the project done - but with js on frontend. Still thank you for the hint to Swagger, I will try that out later I think.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment specifically on the choice of Java technologies as I work in .NET, but have used an approach similar to yours, i.e. create a REST API that your knockout View Models will use. This API is very re-usable.

Knockout specifically will help you create the UI, in common with other MVVM patterns the use observable properties and arrays save a lot of the pain of writing "glue" logic that connects your code to your UI. Most of the code will be in your viewModel, which will contain validation, business logic and application state.Your view will be HTML to display this data.

As such there will be little need for further abstraction that will be re-used.

As you progress you will find that Knokcout is fairly exentsible and you will be able to write a number of custom bindings that will be re-usable in other projects, however there will be unlikely to be much need for further abstraction.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You think, I just should write the js-file using the knockout-features and this is the interface then? So to make it bit more nice, just putting a closure in and that is the lib then?

Comment: The bulk of your js files will most likely be viewModels. This will contain the logic that makes the Html views work. Namespacing this is sensible to avoid collisions in the global namespace. If you find yourself needing to say do some calculus it will make sense to write this as a separate library. If you need custom bindings, e.g. prompt should respond enter key this is a knockout custom binding. Your viewModels contain data and state for your view and are therefore not typically re-usable.

Comment: So, you mean, the viewModel is too specific to be included in such library? This is kind of what I thought. I am still try to figure out, what should be in such library. I have three types of ajax-calls : delete, add, search for words. Are only those and maybe the array, which stores the words, supposed to be in such library? Supposingly I would do that with the module-pattern, I then would add the code of the viewModel into the same js-file beneath it?

Comment: Not necessary to to be in the same file? It's a bit hard to advise on specifics. Perhaps you want a library to wrap calls to your ReST API? So you have common error logging etc.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I think this was supposed to be the purpose. The API to the backend, so to say the REST API. so the functions, add-delete-search including error-logging? And this is it then? How about, if I also deal with knockout-js in the ajax-calls. Is this a too bad design then and I would have to alter this then?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by deal with knockoutjs in the ajax-calls? The decision on whether to make a lib to do the ajax calls or simply couple them to your view model depends on a number of real world factors. Mostly time to write it and how many other projects may want the same thing.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for your constant feedbacks:). Well - yes - real world factors? I want to learn it. This is basically the main factor for that web-app-dictionary project. What I have done so far was "stupidly" creating html-files using jquery and knockout.js for accessing and displaying the data. This works. But actually I was supposed to create a "namespace" rather "library" first, which contains the REST-API. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43766/discussion-between-captain-john-and-meru)

Comment: Yep, good idea:). Just read it now. Hope we'll meet some other time in chat.